# Passing a dynamic variable to an Apex controller on page load

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I have a controller which runs a dynamic SOQL query when it instantiates and makes the results of the query available to the VF Page to access.

I use this controller with several VF pages and pass a value via a URL parameter to tell the controller where to look for the dynamic query it will be running.

I'd like to eliminate the URL parameter altogether and instead hard code the parameter within the VF page.

Is there any way to do this so that the parameter hardcoded in the VF page will be available to the controller when instantiating?

Comment: Would you mind sharing some more details ? I would like to understand how are you using this parameter ?

Comment: Within the constructor I am grabbing a URL parameter which passes a recordID. I then read a text field within the recordID which contains fields I am using within a SOQL query. The SOQL query in the constructor populates a list of objects that is shared publicly.

I would like to replace the usage of the URL parameter

Comment: So this URL parameter contains fields ? Possible to post the code snippet, both VF and class?

Comment: @JosephU. Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). The more details you provide, particularly code you've written, the more likely it is that someone will respond to your question with an answer that you'll find helpful.